# charts disappear on-click? I am using dynamic feature

Tags: rgraph

I am using two different charts on the same page, so when I click on any chart of them the Gauge chart disappear.

```
var gauge1 = new RGraph.Gauge({
            id: 'gauge',
            min:0,
            max: 100,
            value: #{mbCardHistory.creditCardPrecentage},
            options: {
            centery: 120,
            radius: 130,
            anglesStart: RGraph.PI,
            anglesEnd: RGraph.TWOPI,
            needleSize: 85,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            needleType: 'line',
            colorsRanges: [[0,30,'red'], [30,70,'yellow'],[70,100,'#0f0']],
            borderInner: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            borderOuter: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            borderOutline: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            centerpinColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            centerpinRadius: 0,
            textAccessible: true
            }
        }).draw();
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3saJM.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnkA2.png)

Comment: Please add your code that causes that behavior, so the community can provide help. This should be text code, not an image.

Comment: What's this: value: #{mbCardHistory.creditCardPrecentage} ?? There's plenty of basic examples of adjustable Gauge charts in the demos: https://www.rgraph.net/demos/index.html

Comment: This is a JSF expression that returns an array of values, and it not effect on charts, the problem is   that we use 3 different charts (pie, line, gauge) and when I click on one of them the outher one just disappear ..

Comment: Can you post a link to the page so that I can see it for myself.